# fastcgi on Apache http server 2.2.14

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi

I just installed Apache http server 2.2.14.
I want to know how to load fast cgi module in this ?

Is it really faster then mod_cgi ?

Can anyone explain ?

Regards,
Mithun

Comment: Which FastCGI module? mod_fcgid or mod_fastcgi or another one?

Answer (score 0):

`LoadModule fcgid_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_fcgid.so`

Yes, FastCGI is a lot quicker than CGI, at the expense of some additional complexity.